# CSS 100% fluid website

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make a website 100% fluid?

As in, fill the background edge-to-edge with an image, no matter the size of the browser window. Also, have it resize larger or smaller as the browser window changes without neccesarily retaining aspect ratio. Images inside divs and font sizes should obviously resize accordingly and maintain the same amount of white space so the page shows exactly the same content in screens from 800x600 to 4K Ultra HD, being the idea to above any kind of vertical scrollbar. Let's forget about mobile and tablets for a moment.

What I have tried for background:

```
body {
background-image:  url(./Si0rPf7.png);
background-size:   contain;                      
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;            
}
```

Which will fit background as long as the aspect ratio of the image is kept, the moment it changes you will see white spaces on both sides. If cover instead of contain, image will get cropped, which is undesirable if we want to show our whole background to everyone, even if we have to stretch it.

Now, for img src I've had half success with two methods:

```
.image_1 {width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

and

```
  <img src="img/image_1.jpg" width="100%"/>
```

None of them seems able to react to both width and height. Looks like you have to choose between one or other.

For font-size I would just use vw and hope for the best.

Comment: This also just showed up on CodePen today: http://codepen.io/derekjp/pen/avodwL

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Comment: Works. Can I follow the same principle for every part of the website?

Comment: Anywhere there's a background image, this will work.

Comment: But I need to make everything fluid to height and width, not just a background image.

Comment: background-size only applies to background, and will scale and stretch the background image to the size of the container. This doesn't account for the size of your divs or the text size.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the flex model: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/

Comment: But aren't flex model resizes based on width? I'm trying to make something with no vertical scrollbar. Sort of one screen and what you see is what you get, the whole content is right there for you when you load the page and there's nothing you must scroll down to see.

Comment: @thenchanter One of the nice things about the flex model is that you can turn the axis and flow your content any way you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: How would you make this [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdeJNw) liquid to height so instead of a vertical scrollbar the whole content stretches when there's not enough space? I need a solution liquid to height and width. So the green footer will always stick to bottom of the visible window and the rest of elements will fill.

Comment: @thenchanter If you look at the first link I sent you, there are two other examples that are interesting to what you're doing: the sticky footer and the holy grail examples. They pretty much do what you're asking for.